# Can Blood Types Change?

Tags: gene-expression, hematology

I recently heard a radio show where two callers claimed that their blood types had changed. One caller claimed that he was born O-, but recent tests said he was A+. Another caller claimed to change from AB- to AB+. Both callers claim that they had multiple tests before and after the change.

What I noticed is that both cases claim a conversion from Rh- to Rh+, or from type O to some other type. These could potentially be explained by a person carrying a gene for Rh factor or some other blood type, but failing to express the protein. Then the gene starts expressing, changing their blood type.

Of course both stories could be false, intentionally or otherwise. This is purely anecdotal evidence, and one caller claimed that her blood type change was due to extraterrestrial interference. I couldn't find any better documented cases of blood type changes after a quick search on the internet, so I thought I'd ask here.

Are there any documented cases of a change in blood type?

Comment: This is highly unlikely. The only reason which comes to my mind would be a transfer of stem cells (aka bone marrow transplant).

Comment: @Chris And I doubt that aliens are transferring stem cells.

Comment: Embryonic bone marrow transplant, maybe...? But that wouldn't work since they'd tested blood group earlier too ;)

Comment: @another'Homosapien' I would suspect that either the first test was wrong or somebody remembered something wrong.

Comment: @chris my first idea would be: "if your blood type has changed, then your body (immune system) will very soon kill you". It surely isn't easy at all...there has to be some misunderstanding here.

Comment: Possible in leukaemia.

Comment: @another'Homosapien' not in the cases when antigen is not expressed ie. if blood group changes from AB to A or B or O , or from AorB to O.

Comment: @jm97 yeah...I meant that only in cases mentioned here :P

Comment: And how are we 100% sure that hemagglutination will not happen? I also believe that there is a very high death rate, and as a result, there will be no longer human living populations with that symptoms. But what happens if the O- type changes to A+ type, I don't know. And especially how Rh- changes to Rh+, is just a mystery. @user137 Can you provide us a link where we can see if that hypothesis is true? Please check online for that radio conversation you heard. To sum up, what happens with the antigenes? It is extremely lethal to mix the blood types...

Comment: @The_Mad_Fish [This](http://midnightinthedesert.com/) was the show, I think it was the April 13th or 14th shows, but they don't let you listen to past shows without paying, so I can't link to the exact shows. But the evidence I list is the evidence they gave, purely anecdotal. Could the antigens be expressed at such low levels that hemagglutination doesn't happen?

Comment: @user137 No antigenes dont express "mildly" or "in a soft way". Their expression (if it happens, but in our case it happens 100%) is done with an almost sure result (e.g Hemagglutination).

Answer (score 4):

Blood group antigens are either sugars or proteins found attached to the red blood cell membrane. ABO blood group antigens are the most clinically important antigens because they are the most immunogenic. As red blood cell antigens are inherited traits, they are usually not altered throughout the life of an individual. There have been occasional case reports of ABO blood group antigen change in malignant conditions,ABO antigen alteration associated with acute myeloid leukemia. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5242122/

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15135601 ( B to O change)

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22270426 (New laboratory procedures and Rh blood type changes in a pregnant woman.)

A bone marrow transplant will replace the cells which make your blood cells with cells from the donor. Over about 3-4 months (life span of a red cell), your blood will become your donors type.